# "Minimum memory limit allowed is 4MB" failure during the chaincode instantiation

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

After successfully installing the chaincode on each peer, instantiating the chaincode fails because of "Minimum memory limit allowed is 4MB" error.

On orderer, it prints:

```
Error: Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error starting container: API error (400): {"message":"Minimum memory limit allowed is 4MB"}
```

Then, on the peer, it prints:

```
2018-07-10 08:02:35.893 UTC [dockercontroller] Start -> ERRO 610 start-could not recreate container <10.11.1.121-10.11.1.121-mycc-1.0>, because of API error (400): {"message":"Minimum memory limit allowed is 4MB"}
2018-07-10 08:02:35.893 UTC [container] unlockContainer -> DEBU 611 container lock deleted(10.11.1.121-10.11.1.121-mycc-1.0)
2018-07-10 08:02:35.893 UTC [chaincode] Launch -> ERRO 612 launchAndWaitForRegister failed Error starting container: API error (400): {"message":"Minimum memory limit allowed is 4MB"}
2018-07-10 08:02:35.893 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> DEBU 613 Exit
2018-07-10 08:02:35.894 UTC [endorser] simulateProposal -> ERRO 614 failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc"  on transaction c67380e075c9a178cd11b6570cf774c616249a5a1412bdc2f96ebecc3d7bbb7b, error: Error starting container: API error (400): {"message":"Minimum memory limit allowed is 4MB"}
```

How can I handle this error? What exactly does the message mean?

The Fabric version is 1.0-rc and this network is tested on the embedded environment, which has limitations on hardware resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue when running Hyperledger v0.6 on a Raspberry Pi 3.

You need to modify *peer/core.yaml* and change *Memory* value from 2147483648 to something that is lower than your memory size (in my case I just put 134217728 which is less than the 972230656 B of the system):

```
-            Memory: 2147483648
+            Memory: 134217728
```

You may also want to change line 36 of *core/ledger/statemgmt/buckettree/data_key.go*:

```
-       bucketNumber := int(bucketHash)%conf.getNumBucketsAtLowestLevel() + 1
+       bucketNumber := int(bucketHash % uint32(conf.getNumBucketsAtLowestLevel()) + 1)
```

because bucketHash is uint32 and int is 32 bits on a Raspberry Pi (or any other 32-bit system). Thus, you may get a negative bucketNumber which produces this fatal error:

```
panic: Invalid bucket number [-483217]. Bucket nuber at level [9] can be between 1 and [1000003]
```

After you make these changes, recompile peer:

```
$ make peer
```